# How can I write XML in a SQL Server table from one format to another?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a problem. I have a SQL Server table that stores a bunch of XML documents in a column. I need to pass these XML documents to a XML parser, but the format of my starting XML is not in a format the parser can accept. Here's what I have to work with -

XML stored in my SQL Server table is in the following format:

```
<Document ID="207">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <LastModifiedInVersion>1.0</LastModifiedInVersion>
  <Signatures />
  <Controls>
    <Control ID="EmpID">
      <Value>45678</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpFN">
      <Value>Ryn</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpLN">
      <Value>Veris</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpDOB">
      <Value>01/19/1980</Value>
    </Control>
  </Controls>
  <AutoKeys />
</Document>
```

I need to take that XML and make it look like this:

```
<xml_record>
<employee>
    <EmpID value="45678"/>
    <EmpFN value="Ryn"/>
    <EmpLN value="Veris"/>
    <empDOB value="01/19/1980"/>
</employee>
</xml_record>
```

I looked into using XSLT, but it seems to be all based around displaying XML data in a browser and not a translation of the actual format. My ultimate goal is simply to translate the format and use the XML parser to pull the employee values to populate another table, I don't need any of the rest of the original XML. Is what I'm looking to do even possible? If so just pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: don't know if such a library exists for MS enviroments, but that sounds like an XQuery task

Comment: try looking here, seems that SQL Server has some XQuery support. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491/SQL-Server-2005-XQuery-and-XML-DML---Part-1.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xdoc xml = '<Document ID="207">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <LastModifiedInVersion>1.0</LastModifiedInVersion>
  <Signatures />
  <Controls>
    <Control ID="EmpID">
      <Value>45678</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpFN">
      <Value>Ryn</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpLN">
      <Value>Veris</Value>
    </Control>
    <Control ID="EmpDOB">
      <Value>01/19/1980</Value>
    </Control>
  </Controls>
  <AutoKeys />
</Document>
'


SELECT 
    EmpID   'EmpID/@value',
    EmpFN    'EmpFN/@value',
    EmpLN    'EmpLN/@value',
    EmpDOB   'EmpDOB/@value'
FROM (
SELECT 
    @xdoc.query('//Control[@ID = "EmpID"]/Value').value('.','INT') AS EmpID,
    @xdoc.query('//Control[@ID = "EmpFN"]/Value').value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS EmpFN,
    @xdoc.query('//Control[@ID = "EmpLN"]/Value').value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS EmpLN,
    @xdoc.query('//Control[@ID = "EmpDOB"]/Value').value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS EmpDOB
)t
FOR XML PATH('employee'), ROOT('xml_record')
```

Not most elegant, but working.

Comment: Wow I'll have to give that a shot! I'll let you know how it works out, thank you very much for the input!